# Reload Windows Forms variables without reloading form layout

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to reload a form variables?

```
string a = ""

public form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void form1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     a = "Something";
     textbox1.Text = a;
}
```

Is there a way to reset the value of "a" to empty and the text displayed on the textbox? I can create a function to set the value of "a" to empty and empty the textbox but as I have many variables, I want to avoid doing that as I might miss one that will cause a bug. I was wondering if there is a way to do that.

I don't want to reinitialize the form as its kinda slow to reload the form graphics again. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Group all these variables with a structure. Then you can create a new structure by calling its constructor to properly set all variables an initial value ("" for strings) and discard the current one.

Comment: You could also use the DefaultValue attribute on properties, instead of fields - would that work for you?

Comment: I updated my question. I thought of that but do I have to manually set all the values of the textbox and data to other components like listview to empty too?

Comment: however, this makes little difference to what a 'reset' method does. you can always *forget* to do something and cause a bug.

Comment: Basically. I want the form to be in its first load again. Thats what I wanted to do.

Comment: You could do it with reflection, create a custom Attribute to decorate 'resettable' fields and then use reflection to iterate fields and reset them.

Comment: It cannot be easier or more reliable than creating an `Init` method which resets the values. Then call `Init` whenever you need, including in the form load event handler.

Comment: Attribute doesn't make sense here, because the user wants to reset TextBox as well.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei. Yes. I can do that but want to avoid is as I have lots of variable which are crucial for my form. One mistake would cause a bug for sure. I just want the form to reset to when its first loaded. All the variables are empty and all the forms component is empty as it is tied to my variables.

Comment: If there is a propbablity to forget resetting a field, you may also forget to decorate it with an attribute. This applies on all solutions.

Comment: Also unit tests are there to prevent/find such mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I would work like this:

```
public struct Snapshot
{
    public string a;
    public int? b;
}

private Snapshot _initial;

private void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     _initial = this.CreateSnapshot();
}

private Snapshot CreateSnapshot()
{
    return new Snapshot()
    {
        a = textbox1.Text,
        b = int.TryParse(textbox2.Text, out int x) ? (int?)x : null
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.RestoreSnapshot(_initial);
}

private void RestoreSnapshot(Snapshot snapshot)
{
    textbox1.Text = snapshot.a;
    textbox2.Text = snapshot.b.HasValue ? snapshot.b.Value.ToString() : "";
}
```

Your `_initial` `Snapshot` happens at `form1_Load` to save where the form was at at the beginning. You then just call `this.RestoreSnapshot(_initial);` whenever you want to revert your values.

The advantage of this kind of approach is that it allows you to make multiple snapshots and implement an "undo" function and, because you have separated your form from your data, it makes testing easier.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a wrapper around your properties, with change notification? You can then use data binding to make the value and the text boxes update together. See the following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public NotifyProperty<string> A { get; } = new NotifyProperty<string>();
    public NotifyProperty<double> B { get; } = new NotifyProperty<double>();

    public void Reset()
    {
        A.Value = "Something";
        B.Value = 3.14d;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", A, "Value", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", B, "Value", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

        Reset();
    }

    private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Reset();
    }
}

public class NotifyProperty<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private T _value;

    public T Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if (_value != null && _value.Equals(value)) return;
            _value = value; 
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


}
```

When Reset() is called, both the values in A and B and textBox1 and textBox2 will be updated. Also, when you are obtaining the results from the form, you can use A and B (you don't need to use the textboxes, because when the user types text, A and B will be updated automatically).

Answer (score 0):

1. First Form

```cs
public partial class FrmCasher : XtraForm
{
  public static FrmCasher instanceC;
  public SimpleLabelItem num;
  
  public FrmCasher()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    num = lableTableID; // We want to change lableTableID's text value
    instanceC = this;
  }
}
```

2. Second Form

```cs
public partial class FrmHall : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
{
  private void FrmHall_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
  {
    FrmCasher.instanceC.num.Text = "Our new String value...";
  }
}
```

Comment: in this code we change lable text in first form from second form buy adding its value from global variable